# How to make a 2d plataform behave like a piano key in unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a 2D game in unity where my character is small, and I have a level where the character walks along a piano. My question is how can I code the physics for a piano key where the velocity of my character falling on it effects how much it goes down, furthermore when my character leaves said key it goes back to it's normal position of not pressed.

- I've tried thinking about this problem as a spring body, tried some solutions using spring joint 2d component, but it overshoots the position and also doesn't allow me to have it's rigidbody as kinematic, which would be ideal.
- I've also tried coding spring physics with the spring force from Hooke's equation and some additional parameters without any success.

What's to be expected is that the characters falls on a key, it goes down a bit and goes back up after the character leaves the key.

Thank you for all the answers, question formatting tips are welcome as well!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let us define the problem.
We want to move a object a certain vertical distance when the player steps on it.
We can detect that by checking the OnCollisionEnter2D() Event of Rigidbodies.
When detecting a collision, you could access the mass var of the player object or any defined variable.

Then use this defined weight to move the piano key downwards.
If no Collision happens, we move the key back to its original y position.

The weight could be a variable attached to the player object or said Rigidbody Mass Variable.
The part where you move the key can happen however you want.
Via: 
 Transform.Translate
 Rigidbody.AddForce 
 etc ...

So if the Collision.GameObject.Name == "YourPlayerName" && transform.position.y > lowerLimit
Access your RigidBody component and use the AddForce Function.
Somewhwat like blablabla.AddForce(new Vector2(0,-(Collision.rigidbody.mass * someRandomFactorYouWantToMultiplywith))

and else move the piano upwards till you reach the original height.

Im writing this on my phone sry for the format hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm not able to try that solution out right now, but I'll do it when I can, sounds like it might work right! thanks

Comment: No problem, hope it helped you. :)